# Change to frameless and translucent window from function

Tags: qt, shadow

I am tried to change windows style to frameless window with shadow.
It worked only when I put this code in constructor windows, but when this code put in Button Clicked function it doesn't work: MainWindow isn't translucent.
Code:

```
ui->widget->setAutoFillBackground(true);

setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground); 
setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);

QGraphicsDropShadowEffect *bodyShadow = new QGraphicsDropShadowEffect;
bodyShadow->setBlurRadius(10.0);
bodyShadow->setColor(QColor(0,0 , 0, 120));
bodyShadow->setOffset(0,0);

ui->widget->setGraphicsEffect(bodyShadow);

this->show();
```